# How to get result in IResultFilter in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a custom filter action:

```
void IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting (ResultExecutingContext filterContext)        
{
      // code
      var result = ((JsonResult)filterContext.Result).Data;
      // code
}
```

The action controller returns a `JsonResult` and I can't take the values that are displayed in the view, when I inspect 'result' I can see the values, the `JsonResult` is a record modified from a database, I want take these values to build a log in other table.

result is a type of: `object {ProjectName.Models.ModelName}`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. You appear to have gotten the `Result` correctly. Are you trying to figure out how to cast that result as a `ModelName` so you can do something else with it?

Comment: I want to get a parameter from the JsonResult, I made this:  `string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result.Data);`
Now I have a string with all data, it's ok for now but I am searching a right way to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting (ResultExecutingContext filterContext)        
{
      // code
      var jsonResult = (JsonResult)filterContext.Result;
      var model = (ProjectName.Models.ModelName)jsonResult.Data;
      var propertyValue = model.PropertyName;
      // code
}
```